Set volume owner / permission in docker compose
Minimal example of compose.yaml
services:
    my_service:
        image: alpine
        volumes:
            - my_vol:/my_vol
        command: [sh, -c, 'adduser -S -s /bin/sh my_user && su - my_user -c "mkdir /my_vol/my_folder"']
volumes:
    my_vol:

$ docker compose up
[+] Running 2/2
 ✔ Network tests_default         Created
 ✔ Container tests-my_service-1  Created
Attaching to my_service-1
my_service-1  | mkdir: can't create directory '/my_vol/my_folder': Permission denied
my_service-1 exited with code 1
$

I have a service that relies on a shared volume for persistence (in the real example is also shared between multiple services).
Internally the application needs to write in the volume, but it cannot, as you can see from the error. From what I see the mounted folder has rwxr-xr-x permission, and the owner is root, so it cannot be written by my_user
Is there a way to set my_vol options to make it writable? I found https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/07-volumes/#driver_opts where I could set the volume driver options, but that seems applicable only for bind volumes

One way I’ve addressed a similar permission issue with a named volume in the past was by initializing the volume with the correct permissions before my service ran. I used an entrypoint script for this. You can try similar steps :
1. Create an entrypoint script (init.sh):
#!/bin/sh

# Create user and set permissions
adduser -S -s /bin/sh my_user
chown -R my_user:my_user /my_vol

# Execute the command passed to the container
exec "$@"

Make sure to give execute permission to the script:
chmod +x init.sh

2. Adjust your compose.yaml to use the entrypoint script:
version: '3.9'
services:
  my_service:
    image: alpine
    volumes:
      - my_vol:/my_vol
      - ./init.sh:/init.sh # Mount the entrypoint script
    entrypoint: ["/init.sh"]
    command: ["sh", "-c", 'su - my_user -c "mkdir /my_vol/my_folder"']
volumes:
  my_vol:

So basically, the init.sh script creates the user and sets the appropriate permissions on the volume before executing the main command.
The entrypoint script ensures that /my_vol is writable by my_user.
Hope it helps or gives you some idea on a different approach you might want to try.
